# How to split several columns into one column with several records in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to transform the data using SQL but I'm struggling with one thing currently.

I have a table `Person` with these columns:

```
phone_number; name_1; name_2; name3; name4.
```

I need to transform this table to table like this:

```
phone_number; name
```

Where would be such records as

```
(phone_number; name_1)
(phone_number; name_2)
(phone_number; name_3)
```

Please help me (example is below)

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    phone_number int,
    name_1 varchar(50),
    name_2 varchar(50),
    name_3 varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Person (phone_number, name_1, name_2, name_3)
VALUES (123, 'Billy', 'Bill', 'Bi')
    
/* Expected: */

/*
phone_number | name
123: Billy,
123: Bill,
123: Bi
*/
```

I've tried to do this but I'm an absolute beginner and have no idea what to do with raw SQL. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: Please align your example with the script: there's name4 column missing in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` statement.

```
SELECT phone_number, name_1
FROM Person

UNION ALL

SELECT phone_number, name_2
FROM Person

UNION ALL

SELECT phone_number, name_3
FROM Person
```

Please note that `UNION ALL` will not remove duplicates (in case you have the same names for a single `phone_number`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with python pandas?