# How to merge several columns into one column with several records using python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which I need to transform in order to get 2 cols insted of 4 :

```
data = [['123', 'Billy', 'Bill', 'Bi'],
        ['234', 'James', 'J', 'Ji'],
        ['543', 'Floyd', 'Flo', 'F'],
]

processed_data = ?

needed_df = pandas.DataFrame(processed_data, columns=['Number', 'Name'])
```

I expect the following behaviour:

```
['123', 'Billy']
['123', 'Bill']
['123', 'Bi']
['234', 'James']
['234', 'J']
['234', 'Ji']
```

I've tried to use for in for loop but getting the wrong result:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        new_row = ...
        processed_df = pandas.concat(df, new_row)
```

Such a construction gives a too big result

The similar question using sql:

[How to split several columns into one column with several records in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680816/how-to-split-several-columns-into-one-column-with-several-records-in-sql)

Comment: What did you try? What result did it yield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can convert you exists data into a dataframe then perform pandas dataframe reshaping with `melt`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['123', 'Billy', 'Bill', 'Bi'],
        ['234', 'James', 'J', 'Ji'],
        ['543', 'Floyd', 'Flo', 'F'],
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.melt(0).sort_values(0)
```

Output:

```
     0  variable  value
0  123         1  Billy
3  123         2   Bill
6  123         3     Bi
1  234         1  James
4  234         2      J
7  234         3     Ji
2  543         1  Floyd
5  543         2    Flo
8  543         3      F
```

Answer (score 1):

Let use list comprehension to create pairs of Name and Number then create a new dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([[x, z] for x, *y in data for z in y], columns=['Number', 'Name'])
```

---

```
  Number   Name
0    123  Billy
1    123   Bill
2    123     Bi
3    234  James
4    234      J
5    234     Ji
6    543  Floyd
7    543    Flo
8    543      F
```